# sweet potato dish - what can i prepare ahead with my recipe

Tags: potatoes, thanksgiving, casserole, sweet

I made a recipe with fresh sweet potatoes last year - on Thanksgiving day.  It was time consuming and I'd like to do what I can ahead.  The recipe also has alcohol in the casserole.

1. Can I peel, cut and freeze or refrigerate the slices ahead - and if so - which one - freeze or refrigerate.  Also how much in advance
2. Can I go beyond that - to make the whole thing - brown sugar, bourbon - etc. ahead - what is best to do ahead and how long ahead can I do it.

THANKS

Comment: Welcome to SA!  Folks will be able to help you a lot better if you share what dish the recipe was for.  It sounds like maybe a sweetened sweet potato casserole, but you don't actually say.

Comment: It’s up to you, but I actually enjoy our family gatherings when my cousins and I work together to finish prepping meals.  I remember one Thanksgiving where my cousin was making something with pearl onions and 4 of us pealed tiny little onions (as we didn’t know about the boiling them trick at the time)

Answer (score 3):

It would help to have the entire recipe, but in general, any sweet potato casserole can be made ahead in its entirety, chilled and refrigerated, even a couple of days in advance. Then, on the day of the meal, just reheat in the oven.

Comment: Typically for casseroles. I cook them through but don’t attempt to brown the top.  On the day to serve it, I warm it up slowly (covered, perhaps 300°F / 150°C) until warmed through, then remove the cover and turn up the heat (or switch to broil/grill if the container can handle it) and brown the top if appropriate.   I think there’s a question about reheating casseroles on here that might have more details

Answer (score 0):

Freezing potato slices is not the answer, but storing them in the fridge, fully submerged in a liquid (water, milk, broth, bourbon), should do the trick for a couple days.  As we don't know your recipe, select a soaking medium that pairs with your recipe.

Comment: sweet potatoes are different than regular potatoes, in that refrigerating them can make them never soften once cooked. Do not refrigerate raw sweet potatoes. Source: Cook's Illustrated's *The Science of Good Cooking*